# How to handle image corrupt or truncated error in phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Getting an error 'Image corrupt or truncated' while working on localhost in firefox,but the same page on server doesn't produce such an error.I have used the same page for developing an android app using phonegap and on loading the image my app gets terminated,'Force quit'.

I have embedded the image using the following code:-

```
$("#logo").attr('src', 'url');
```

and the html code is as follows:

```
<img style="width:190px; height: 145px; margin-top: 0%;" id="logo"/>
```

Such error occurs when displaying some images only,for rest it works fine.
Kindly mention a way to handle this error for such images.

Answer (score 0):

You could try atatching a jQuery error handler to the image element.

```
$('#logo').error(function() {
    alert('An error occurred when loading the image!.')
}).attr("src", URL);
```

You can chain the calls to `.error()` and `attr()` so that you don't have to execute two commands.

The error callback will trigger when there is a JavaSctipt error that was raised on that element.

Taken from [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/error/) -

> The error event is sent to elements, such as images, that are referenced by a document and loaded by the browser. It is called if the element was not loaded.

Some more relevant information regarding your issue (working locally) -

> **The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error event**, which is why the example sets the src attribute after attaching the handler. Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally; **error relies on HTTP status codes and will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.**

Comment: are you positive that this code is causing the crash?  are there any other commands being executed when the image is loaded?  could there be a problem with the image itself?

Comment: The image is the problem...while displaying one particular image only am getting this error....can u please suggest a way to handle the error...

Comment: it could be a corrupt file... can you open the image and save it in a new file?

Comment: The image is corrupted but i am supposed to handle or show an error message and save the app from crashing....

Comment: what about an ugly old `try catch` to attempt to contain the error?  I've never heard of a corrupt image crashing the entire browser but then again I don't have much experience in mobile development...